# How to update Ruby 2.2.4 to 2.2..5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

The reason I need to update to 2.2.5 is because whenever I run bundle install I'm receiving an error:

> ERROR:  Error installing ruby_dep:
>
> ruby_dep requires Ruby version >= 2.2.5, ~> 2.2.

So I guess in order to avoid this I need to update to 2.2.5
I went to https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2016/04/26/ruby-2-2-5-released/ and I downloaded the first link. I ended up with a ZIP file that I have no clue what to do with.
I tried another method with: `$ ruby update --system`
but got in return

> c:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.2.0\bin\ruby.exe: No such file or directory -- update (LoadError)

What should I do?
Note: I'm using windows

Comment: Which is the gem depending on ruby_dep? Which rails version are you actually using? Maybe you could also tag your question with 'windows'.

Comment: i don't think you can just 'bump' ruby versions, what's better is to keep both versions installed and use RVM or Rbenv. DOn't know about windows though.

Comment: @Felix I'm using Rails 4.2.5.2. Could it be that I have to upgrade to 5.0.0? Also the root of the problem is this: i ran rake db:setup for an application I'm building and I received:

Could not find gem 'rails (= 3.2.11) x86-mingw32' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

So I did:

InstallError: ruby_dep requires Ruby version >= 2.2.5, ~> 2.2.
An error occurred while installing ruby_dep (1.5.0), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install ruby_dep -v '1.5.0'` succeeds before bundling.

Comment: @maxpleaner Zak is on Windows, so rbenv and RVM are not available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you used Rails Installer to get Ruby set up initially, you will need to download an updated version of RailsInstaller. Unfortunately, it's current 2.2 installer includes 2.2.4.

One suggestion would be to remove RailsInstaller and use [RubyInstaller](http://rubyinstaller.org) instead. Unfortunately, then you would also need to set up other tools, such as Git, a database, etc.

The other thing you could try is going to an older version of `ruby_dep`, it appears that `1.3.1` would be suitable for you. This is dependent upon the rest of your project, since it's possible you need the current version of `ruby_dep`.

Comment: Sounds logical. I did install ruby_dep 1.3.1. But when I run bundle install again it still returns the same error (Error installing ruby_dep:
        ruby_dep requires Ruby version >= 2.2.5, ~> 2.2.)
How do I make it use ruby_dep 1.3.1 by default instead of 1.5.0?

Comment: Your Gemfile entry for `ruby_dep` needs to read `gem 'ruby_dep', '~> 1.3.1'`. Then run bundle again, and hopefully there aren't any issues resolving dependencies.

Comment: Would it be possible to list all the requisites/tools that I need if I use RubyInstaller? Other than Git and a database... Thanks!

Comment: @ZakJanzi It's just tools listed on the RailsInstaller page. After you install Ruby via RubyInstaller, then you'll need to install Devkit (from RubyInstaller website). Then install the bundler gem `gem installer bundler`, and whatever DBs you need. You could look into using the Linux Shell for Windows 10, I've heard it's decent for Ruby.